# БаловАть и бАловать

Tags: фонетика

Известно, что правильно говорить "баловАть", но большинство все равно говорят "бАловать". Я знаю, что подобные вопросы тут уже обсуждались, но все-таки интересно, откуда такое несоответствие? Может, конечно, я какая-то дико невежественная, но, признаться, я даже не могу вспомнить кого-то, кто бы в быту говорил "баловАть" или "балУюсь".

Answer (score 1):

Ударение считается правильным, как правило, если оно совпадает с ударением большинства аналогичных слов. Если рассматривать аналоги баловать, то мы видим: *волновАть, пожинАть, рассказАть, нагибАть* и т. п. Как видим ударение в основном ставится на звук [а]. Исключением из этого правила будут недавно заимствованные слова *телефонИровать, делегИровать, ангажИровать и ряд других.

Из этого можно сделать вывод, что традиционное ударение на "-ать", ныне начинает смещаться к началу слова, что начинает влиять и на ударение в словавах с традиционным ударением на "-ать". Например гораздо чаще мне приходилось слышать слова *бомбадИровать* и *бАловать*, чем их орфоэпически верные варианты. Широкому распространению неверного варианта способствовало неправильное произнесение слова Борисом Ливановым, озвучивавшим Карлсона в известном советском мультфильме. Может быть помните эту фразу, - "А мы тут, знаете ли, плюшками бАлуемся".